# Encrypted at rest persistent volume in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, security, encryption, storage

Is there a recommended approach to using encrypted file system for persistent volumes in kubernetes?

Perhaps mounting a LUKS fs disk image file ?

Comment: Thank you for posting a question. Could you modify the question so that it contains the attempts you have done in order to solve the issue?